# Filtering through Duplicates in Bigquery

Tags: filter, google-bigquery, duplicates

I have some data in a bigquery table that contains 3 relevant data fields: 
A, B and C

A + B SHOULD be a unique pair; This means that a value from column B should  NOT have multiple, different, values from Column A.

```
A         B        C
1111      XXXX10   2019-01-01
1111      XXXX10   2019-01-02
1111      XXXX10   2019-01-03
1111      XXXX10   2019-01-04
2222      XXXX11   2019-01-01
2222      XXXX11   2019-01-02
2222      XXXX11   2019-01-03
3333      XXXX12   2019-01-01
4444      XXXX13   2019-01-01
5555      XXXX10   2019-01-01
6666      XXXX11   2019-01-03
```

In the above example, i want to run a query where: Column B > 1 unique value in column A values. The data sample above would return the result below:

```
A         B        C
2222      XXXX11   2019-01-03   
6666      XXXX11   2019-01-03
1111      XXXX10   2019-01-01
5555      XXXX10   2019-01-01
```

any suggestions would be great
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a, b, ANY_VALUE(c) c
FROM (
  SELECT b, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a, c)) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY b
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a) > 1
), UNNEST(arr)
GROUP BY a, b
```

If to apply to sample data from your question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1111 a, 'XXXX10' b, '2019-01-01' c UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111, 'XXXX10', '2019-01-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111, 'XXXX10', '2019-01-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111, 'XXXX10', '2019-01-04' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, 'XXXX11', '2019-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, 'XXXX11', '2019-01-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, 'XXXX11', '2019-01-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333, 'XXXX12', '2019-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444, 'XXXX13', '2019-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5555, 'XXXX10', '2019-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6666, 'XXXX11', '2019-01-03' 
)
```

result is

```
Row a       b       c    
1   1111    XXXX10  2019-01-01   
2   5555    XXXX10  2019-01-01   
3   2222    XXXX11  2019-01-01   
4   6666    XXXX11  2019-01-03
```